# I am getting only first data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

> I am trying to extract the sang data from the spotify. In the for loop
> if i use find all i am getting the following value. [{'image': [, , ], 'title': [Dying
> Man, Morgan Wallen,
> One Thing At A
> Time, Red
> Ruby Da Sleeze, Nicki Minaj,
> Red Ruby Da
> Sleeze, El
> Merengue, Marshmello, Manuel Turizo, El Merengue]}]
>
> like entire tag value and its not writing the value in json file.
> showing the following error
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\santh\PycharmProjects\webScrapping\sptipy.py", line 42, in
>
> json.dump(res, f, indent=8, ensure_ascii=False)   File "C:\Users\santh\miniconda3\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 179, in dump
> for chunk in iterable:   File "C:\Users\santh\miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 429, in
> _iterencode
> yield from _iterencode_list(o, _current_indent_level)   File "C:\Users\santh\miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 325, in
> _iterencode_list
> yield from chunks   File "C:\Users\santh\miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in
> _iterencode_dict
> yield from chunks   File "C:\Users\santh\miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 325, in
> _iterencode_list
> yield from chunks   File "C:\Users\santh\miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in
> _iterencode
> o = _default(o)   File "C:\Users\santh\miniconda3\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
> raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.**class**.**name**} ' TypeError: Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable
>
> in the for loop if i use find(like in the code) i am getting only one
> value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


def json_from_html_using_bs4(base_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(base_url)

    driver.maximize_window()
    element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='JUa6JJNj7R_Y3i4P8YUX']")))
    driver.implicitly_wait(60)
    # get all of the current page's html
    page_html = driver.page_source
    # page = requests.get(base_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")

    songs = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "ShMHCGsT93epRGdxJp2w Ss6hr6HYpN4wjHJ9GHmi"})

    res = []
    for song in songs:
        title = song.find('a').text
        image = song.find('img')['src']
        i = {'image': image, 'title': title}
        res.append(i)
    print(res)
    return res



if __name__ == "__main__":
    base_url = "https://open.spotify.com/playlist/37i9dQZF1DX4JAvHpjipBk"
    res = json_from_html_using_bs4(base_url)

    with open('song.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(res, f, indent=8, ensure_ascii=False)
```

> ---
>
> 1. output [
>    {
>    "image": "https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d00004851fda3d35cd6d88c35f82a492e",
>    "title": "Dying Man"
>    } ]

Comment: you can try convert to str(): title = str(song.find('a').text)
        image = str(song.find('img')['src'])

Comment: getting only one data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution, Now you can see a list of 25 songs. And if you want to scrape all 100 songs, you'll need to scroll down to the bottom of the page to get all 100 songs

```
def json_from_html_using_bs4(base_url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(base_url)

    driver.maximize_window()
    
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//div[@class='JUa6JJNj7R_Y3i4P8YUX']")))
    driver.implicitly_wait(60)

    page_html = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, "html.parser")
    container = soup.find("div", attrs={"role": "presentation", "style": "transform: translateY(0px);"})
    songs = container.find_all('div', attrs={"aria-selected": "false", "role": "row"})
    res = []
    for song in songs:
        data = {
        "image": song.find('img')['src'],
        "title": song.find('a').text,
        "album": song.find_all_next('div', attrs={"class":"bfQ2S9bMXr_kJjqEfcwA"})[0].text,
        "duration": song.findNext('div', attrs={"class": "Type__TypeElement-sc-goli3j-0 dvSMET Btg2qHSuepFGBG6X0yEN"}).text,
        }
        res.append(data)
    print(res)
    return res
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me and I added the code for scroll and get the data and did some minor changes in the attributes. It is pulling the entire playlist.